# How to create forecasted values chart using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have some data where I have actual and then forecasted values. Is there a way I can represent this using openpyxl?

Data

```
    Actual   Forecast
jan 100k  
feb 115k
mar 121k
apr 150k
may 137k
jun 125k
jul          167k
aug          184k
sep          202k
oct          223k
nov          245k
dec          269k
```

Desired

[image]

Doing

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    LineChart,
    BarChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

path = "C:/Users/tanisha.hudson/wb1.xlsx"
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = LineChart()

v1 = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=13)
c1.add_data(v1, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)

c1.x_axis.title = 'Chart Title'
c1.y_axis.majorGridlines = None
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: What do you get when you run your code now? Do you get errors? From the openpyxl docs for [Line Charts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html#id1), you seem to be missing calls to `.add_chart` and `.save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Line Chart](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html) with 2 series: 1 series where the Y-axis values are from the Actual column and 1 series where the Y-axis values are from the Forecast column. Both series will use the months from the 1st column as the X-axis values.

The steps are:

1. Define a [`LineChart`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html)
2. Define a [`Reference`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.reference.html) for the range of the cells for the X and Y values.
3. Use `.add_data` or `.append` to add the Y values as a `Series`
4. Use [`.set_categories`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html?highlight=set_categories#id1) to add the X values (as labels)
5. Add the chart to the sheet using `.add_chart`

The problem with your data is that all your numbers have a `k` suffix, which makes it non-numeric and can't be plotted properly by openpyxl (Even in Excel, it is treated as text and is equivalent to 0 when plotted). I assume "100k" means "100,000", so to make things simpler let's just use "100" instead of "100k" and just put that "k" in the label like "Actual (k)".

If you already have that data in an Excel file like this:

[image: input]

Then the code for plotting that in a `LineChart` is as follows:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference, Series

# path = "C:/Users/tanisha.hudson/wb1.xlsx"
path = 'wb1.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active

c1 = LineChart()
c1.title = 'Chart Title'
c1.legend.position = 'b'  # https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/chart_layout.html#legend-layout

actual_values = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=13)
actual_series = Series(actual_values, title_from_data=True)
c1.append(actual_series)

forecast_values = Reference(ws, min_col=3, max_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=13)
forecast_series = Series(forecast_values, title_from_data=True)
c1.append(forecast_series)

xaxis_values = Reference(ws, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=13)
c1.set_categories(xaxis_values)

ws.add_chart(c1, 'E2')
wb.save('wb1-chart.xlsx')
```

Notes:

1. Rows/Columns start at 1 (not 0 like in typical arrays). So for example, the `actual_values` references the range column B and row 1-13.
2. The row with the header "Actual" and "Forecast" is included because in creating the `Series`, we use `title_from_data=True`. You can omit the header row and set the `Series` title separately using the `title=` parameter.
3. Don't forget to call `.add_chart` to add the Line Chart to the sheet. Also, it's better to `.save` it as a separate file in case you mess up the original sheet.

Output:

[image: output - unconnected]

Notice that the 2 series are not connected, since the Actual and Forecast data values are also not connected. A workaround is to add a common data point. For example, add Jun=125 to the Forecast column ():

```py
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
ws['C7'].value = ws['B7'].value  # Copy last Actual as Forecast

...
```

[image: output - connected]

Now if your input data really has a `k` suffix, and you don't want to manually modify them to get rid of that `k`, just use openpyxl to rewrite those values before plotting:

```py
for row in range(2, 14):  # B2-B13, C2-C13
    for col in range(2, 4):  # B-C
        cell = ws.cell(column=col, row=row)
        old_val = cell.value
        new_val = int(old_val.replace('k', '')) if old_val else ''
        cell.value = new_val
ws['C7'].value = ws['B7'].value
```

For more info, see the [Charts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html#charts) section of the openpyxl docs.
In case some features are version-specific: Python 3.8.8, openpyxl 3.0.7, Office 2016.

Comment: Thank you @Gino - could you look at my latest post? It deals with the transparency of the area chart. I have been researching this and could not figure out how to add a layer of transparency. Thanks